# declare parameter in visual studio for creating logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Hi I have created a logic app in azure portal and it is working fine and I am very new to logic app and I need to re create the same logic app in visual studio which i was trying from my end .

So first thing I saw that I am not able to create a parameter in side the logic app as I was creating a logic app through open with visual studio

Please let me know how to declare a parameter in visual studio app designer and how to use it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use the logic app in visual studio, there isn't a button for us to create the parameters directly. But we can do it in the "Code View", please refer to the steps below:

**1.** I created a logic app in visual studio and click the "Code View", we can see the code of the logic app. And we can also find a `parameters` field in the code.
[image]

**2.** We just need to add the parameter which we want to add under the `parameters` field.
[image]

**3.** Then we can use the `param1` we declared in the designer.
[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: thanks for the answer yes i am able to  create a new variable and use it ... just a question some one told to use  logicapp.jason.parameter to decalare parameter.. please let me know what is is used for and when we should it ???

Comment: @RohitKumarSingh The "LogicApp.parameters.json" just used to set the value of the parameter. If we didn't set the defaultValue of the parameter in "LogicApp.json" as I provided above, it will use the value which defined in "LogicApp.parameters.json" when deploy the logic to azure portal.